# Scailing and keeping names of features

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I tried to scale features in my data frame however it also results in losing all names in my df
Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
scaler = RobustScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
pd.DataFrame(X_train)
```

Output data:
[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1reG.png)

Data that I had before it
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdyYn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if X has the desired column names the use

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=X.columns)
```